# Can goblins or orcs see the light Sting gives off?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, weapon

In LOTR, the sword Sting glows whenever goblins or orcs are nearby enough, and in the movies, it can get pretty bright. Can they see this light? If so, has it ever given the wielder away?

Comment: I would be surprised if they didn't, as after all it's just light. However, by the time they see it, it's probably from up close and then boom they're killed by Gandalf/Legolas/Sam/Aragorn etc :)

Comment: My thought was that the light might either be out of their color range (intentionally made that way by the elf blacksmiths), or the sword shine can only be seen by known allies/good hearts (via magic).

Comment: That's true, it always seemed like a tactical disadvantage if you were on a stealth run.

Comment: @Imperator That's what scabbards are for.

Comment: @MattGutting Not if you were about to slit an orc's throat when he saw the glow. Scabbards stop you from seeing it too.

Comment: If you were sneaking up that close to the goblins, you wouldn't need the glow to tell you where they were ;-)

Comment: There might also be more to it than sight.  Does the sword's light hurt goblins and orcs?  Elf magic has that effect on Smeagol.

Comment: I may be mistaken, but when Bilbo first discovers the ring, doesn't he drop Sting while it's glowing, and Gollum completely misses it? I think that would imply that Gollum, at least, can't see the glow.

Comment: @TBear - If I can trust my memory on this, Sting was glowing because of a goblin that arrived in Gollum's lair at the same time as Bilbo.  Gollum killed the goblin before noticing Bilbo, causing the light to go out.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Yes.  In this passage from *The Hobbit*, chapter IV, the goblins can clearly see Orcrist and Glamdring. Sting was of the same make, so there is no reason to believe that its light would be any different.

> At this point Gandalf fell behind, and Thorin with him. They turned a sharp corner. “About turn!” he shouted. “Draw your sword Thorin!”
>
> There was nothing else to be done; and the goblins did not like it. They came scurrying round the corner in full cry, and found Goblin-cleaver, and Foe-hammer shining cold and bright right in their astonished eyes.

Comment: I love how there seems to be a canonical answer to almost any LOTR question.

Comment: "Shining" often refers to reflected light. Mundane non-glowing swords are sometimes described as shining. There is nothing in the quote to suggest that the goblins perceive the swords as glowing.

Comment: Occam's Razor suggests it is far more likely that they *can* see the glow without any evidence to the contrary.

Answer (score 25):

The glow is visible to anyone who can see the blade. However it appears the sheath completely masks the glow as Aragorn is unable to see the blade glowing while it was sheathed.

> **'Let us see what Sting may show,' answered Aragorn.**
>
> **Frodo then drew the elf-blade from its sheath. To his dismay the edges
>   gleamed dimly in the night.** 'Orcs!' he said. 'Not very near, and yet too 
>   near, it seems.’
>
> 'I feared as much,' said Aragorn. 'But maybe they are not on this side
>   of the River. **The light of Sting is faint,** and it may point to no more
>   than spies of Mordor roaming on the slopes of Amon Lhaw. I have never
>   heard before of Orcs upon Amon Hen. Yet who knows what may happen in
>   these evil days, now that Minas Tirith no longer holds secure the
>   passages of Anduin. We must go warily tomorrow.’
>   <sub>*The Fellowship of the Ring: Chapter 10 - The Breaking of the Fellowship* <sup>(emphasis mine)</sup></sub>

There is no instance in the books where the glow caused the wielder's presence to become known prematurely.

Comment: "I have never heard before of *Ores* upon Amon Hen." Yet there they are, my good Lord, and ready for smithing! Wondrous implements could be made with such high-quality raw material...

Comment: @ANeves - Ha! Fixed.